# Is there a way to clear the cache after a docker image is built?

Tags: 9

I have a set up that uses docker to build an image of Drupal 9.

I am trying to update the server to use PHP 8 which is done through the Dockerfile. When I run this set up locally I get an error initially, but I am able to log into the docker container through terminal and can run `drush cr` to rebuild the cache. Once this is done the site loads.

I can't use terminal or use any type of CLI on the server, so I am unable to do this command on the server.

I added `$settings['rebuild_access'] = TRUE;` to the settings.php file so I could go to /core/rebuild.php but I get an error on this page.

These are the errors I get -

On the homepage -

The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.
PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory in Drupal\Component\DependencyInjection\PhpArrayContainer->createService() (line 79 of /opt/app-root/src/web/core/lib/Drupal/Component/DependencyInjection/PhpArrayContainer.php).

Drupal\Component\DependencyInjection\PhpArrayContainer->createService(Array, 'database') (Line: 177)
Drupal\Component\DependencyInjection\Container->get('database', 1) (Line: 212)
Drupal\Component\DependencyInjection\PhpArrayContainer->resolveServicesAndParameters(Array) (Line: 62)
Drupal\Component\DependencyInjection\PhpArrayContainer->createService(Array, 'cache.container') (Line: 177)
Drupal\Component\DependencyInjection\Container->get('cache.container') (Line: 565)
Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel->getCachedContainerDefinition() (Line: 942)
Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel->initializeContainer() (Line: 487)
Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel->boot() (Line: 716)
Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel->handle(Object) (Line: 19)

On update.php -

The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.
PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory in Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder->createService() (line 1130 of /opt/app-root/src/vendor/symfony/dependency-injection/ContainerBuilder.php).

Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder->createService(Object, Array, 1, 'database') (Line: 618)
Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder->doGet('database', 1) (Line: 558)
Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder->get('database') (Line: 752)
Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel->handleException(Object, Object, 1) (Line: 82)
Drupal\Core\Update\UpdateKernel->handle(Object) (Line: 27)

On /core/rebuild.php -

Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory in /opt/app-root/src/web/core/modules/mysql/src/Driver/Database/mysql/Connection.php:189 Stack trace: #0 /opt/app-root/src/web/core/modules/mysql/src/Driver/Database/mysql/Connection.php(189): PDO->__construct('mysql:host=;por...', '', '', Array) #1 /opt/app-root/src/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Database/Database.php(463): Drupal\mysql\Driver\Database\mysql\Connection::open(Array) #2 /opt/app-root/src/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Database/Database.php(188): Drupal\Core\Database\Database::openConnection('default', 'default') #3 [internal function]: Drupal\Core\Database\Database::getConnection('default') #4 /opt/app-root/src/web/core/lib/Drupal/Component/DependencyInjection/Container.php(255): call_user_func_array(Array, Array) #5 /opt/app-root/src/web/core/lib/Drupal/Component/DependencyInjection/Container.php(177): Drupal\Component\DependencyInjection\Container->createService(Array, 'database') #6 /opt/app-root/src/web/core/lib/Drupal/Component/DependencyInjection/Container.php(434): Drupal\Component\DependencyInjection\Container->get('database', 1) #7 /opt/app-root/src/web/core/lib/Drupal/Component/DependencyInjection/Container.php(237): Drupal\Component\DependencyInjection\Container->resolveServicesAndParameters(Array) #8 /opt/app-root/src/web/core/lib/Drupal/Component/DependencyInjection/Container.php(177): Drupal\Component\DependencyInjection\Container->createService(Array, 'cache.backend.d...') #9 /opt/app-root/src/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Cache/ChainedFastBackendFactory.php(83): Drupal\Component\DependencyInjection\Container->get('cache.backend.d...') #10 /opt/app-root/src/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Cache/CacheFactory.php(83): Drupal\Core\Cache\ChainedFastBackendFactory->get('bootstrap') #11 [internal function]: Drupal\Core\Cache\CacheFactory->get('bootstrap') #12 /opt/app-root/src/web/core/lib/Drupal/Component/DependencyInjection/Container.php(255): call_user_func_array(Array, Array) #13 /opt/app-root/src/web/core/lib/Drupal/Component/DependencyInjection/Container.php(177): Drupal\Component\DependencyInjection\Container->createService(Array, 'cache.bootstrap') #14 /opt/app-root/src/web/core/lib/Drupal/Component/DependencyInjection/Container.php(434): Drupal\Component\DependencyInjection\Container->get('cache.bootstrap', 1) #15 /opt/app-root/src/web/core/lib/Drupal/Component/DependencyInjection/Container.php(237): Drupal\Component\DependencyInjection\Container->resolveServicesAndParameters(Array) #16 /opt/app-root/src/web/core/lib/Drupal/Component/DependencyInjection/Container.php(177): Drupal\Component\DependencyInjection\Container->createService(Array, 'module_handler') #17 /opt/app-root/src/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/DrupalKernel.php(602): Drupal\Component\DependencyInjection\Container->get('module_handler') #18 /opt/app-root/src/web/core/includes/utility.inc(35): Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel->preHandle(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request)) #19 /opt/app-root/src/web/core/rebuild.php(51): drupal_rebuild(Object(Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader), Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request)) #20 {main} thrown in /opt/app-root/src/web/core/modules/mysql/src/Driver/Database/mysql/Connection.php on line 189

If there is a way I can add this `drush cr` command to run in the Dockerfile then I think I can get it to work, since that works on my local setup.

Although if this issue can be resolved a different way then that is fine as well

Comment: Sounds like a Docker question not Drupal. AFAIK that could be in the way the container is initiated, or a RUN in the Dockerfile. https://docs.docker.com/reference/dockerfile/#run